# Is it acceptable to omit 来 in 起来 as a direction complement?

Tags: grammar, direction-complement

In the following sentence:

> 在帐篷里，周海提议大家一起唱羌族民歌，渐渐地场面也活跃起来。周海还给他们讲羌族的文化和历史。孩子们渐渐**建立起**对他的信任。

I wonder why it is 起, not 起来 in the sentence above. In my understanding, [the correct complement (direction complement) is 起来](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Direction_complement_%22-qilai%22), but in this sentence it does not have 来.

So is it correct that this usage of 起 is direction complement as well? In that case, why is it 起, not 起来?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**起**

> （用在动词后，表示动词的趋向）:
>
> hold high the flag; raise the flag;
>
> 举起旗子
>
> take up arms;
>
> 拿起武器

As you can see, the verb should be followed by 起 when there is an object at the end, for example 拿起武器. When there's no object, 起来 should be used, e.g. 拿起来. Basically, you can consider 拿起 as a transitive and 拿起来 as an intransitive.

You can also use 把. It will be like 把...拿起来. e.g.  把武器拿起来.

So, 孩子们渐渐建立起对他的信任 can be paraphrased as 孩子们渐渐**把**对他的信任**建立起来**.

Comment: I've never thought about transitivity like that in that case. It's a really nice way to see it.